# Cannot click SVG Path inside Android WebView (Scaloid & AngularJS)

Tags: android, angularjs, scala, svg, webview

I'm making an Android app with Scala([Scaloid](https://github.com/pocorall/scaloid/)) using WebView, that shows my own webpage made with AngularJS.

In my WebView, clickable Svg  elements are generated with ng-repeat.
The problem is, when tapping the  elements through my app, it shows the following error.

> E/webcoreglue﹕ Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found

I've looked for some questions with the problem similar to me, like

- [Android WebView JellyBean -> Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090899/android-webview-jellybean-should-not-happen-no-rect-based-test-nodes-found)

I also tried to make extended WebView class as written in...

- [Android - Extended WebView class causing ClassCastException on Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920757/android-extended-webview-class-causing-classcastexception-on-initialization)

...But they just didn't matter. (in the last case, the app showed "Error inflating class mypackage.SVGWebView")

---

Although it works perfectly when I browsed the page in Chrome for Android, it doesn't in my app.
Could somebody please tell me how could I fix it?
My source code is as follows.

#### SVGWebView.scala

```
    class SVGWebView(c:Context, attrs:AttributeSet, defStyle:Int) extends WebView(c,attrs,defStyle) {
        override def onTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean = {
        if (e.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            val temp_ScrollY:Int = getScrollY
            scrollTo(getScrollX, getScrollY + 1)
            scrollTo(getScrollX, temp_ScrollY)
        }
        super.onTouchEvent(e)
    }
    }
```

#### MainActivity.scala

```
    onCreate { //Scaloid
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       val wv = find[SVGWebView](R.id.webView)
       wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient {
         override def onPageFinished(v: WebView, url: String) {
           val p = find[RelativeLayout](R.id.loadingPanel)
           p.visibility(View.GONE)
         }
       })
       wv.setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(true)
       wv.setInitialScale(1)
       val wvs = wv.getSettings
       wvs.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
       wvs.setSupportZoom(false)
       wvs.setBuiltInZoomControls(false)
       wvs.setUseWideViewPort(true)
       wvs.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)
       wv.loadUrl(home + "index.html?" + mySession.sessionId)
       wv.clearCache(true)
       wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
       override def onConsoleMessage(cm:ConsoleMessage): Boolean = {
           Log.d("MainActivity", cm.message() + "--From line " + cm.lineNumber() + " of " + cm.sourceId())
           true
         }
       })
     }
```

#### index.html

```
    <body ng-controller="container" onload="preload()">
    <div id="container">
    <svg ng-click="popDown($event)" id="map" viewBox="0 0 750 750" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g ng-click="popUp($event);$event.stopPropagation();" id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in items" data-title="{{item.title}}" data-category="{{item.category}}">
        <image xlink:href="foo.gif" ng-attr-x="{{x(item.appearance)}}" ng-attr-y="{{y(item.appearance)}}" height="60px" width="60px"/>
        <path ng-attr-d="{{d(item.appearance)}}" ng-attr-fill="{{fill(item.category, item.appearance.shape)}}" ng-attr-stroke="{{stroke(item.category, item.appearance.shape)}}" ng-attr-stroke-width="{{strokeWidth(item.appearance.shape)}}" />
        </g>
    </svg>
    ...
    </div>
    </body>
```

---

Comment: I have got over the InflatingException "Error inflating class mypackage.SVGWebView" by changing the parameters of SVGWebView to (c:Context, attrs:AttributeSet), But the "no-rect" error is still here.

Comment: Sorry, it's resolved! The problem was just caused by CSS. the <svg> tag was set "position: fixed;" before, but when changed to "position: absolute", the "no rect" error has gone for some reason. Why?